# What's the meaning of "##" in a C++ macro?

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

What's the meaning of "##" in the following?

```
#define CC_SYNTHESIZE(varType, varName, funName)\
protected: varType varName;\
public: inline varType get##funName(void) const { return varName; }\
public: inline void set##funName(varType var){ varName = var; }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The operator ## concatenates two arguments leaving no blank spaces between them:
e.g.

```
#define glue(a,b) a ## b
glue(c,out) << "test";
```

This would also be translated into:

```
cout << "test";
```

Answer (score 1):

*This is called token pasting or token concatenation.*

The **##** (double number sign) operator concatenates two tokens in a macro invocation (text and/or arguments) given in a macro definition.

Take a look [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html#Concatenation) at the official GNU GCC compiler documentation for more information.

Answer (score 1):

It concatenates tokens without leaving blanks between them. Basically, if you didn't have the ## there

```
public: inline varType getfunName(void) const { return varName; }\
```

the precompiler would not replace `funName` with the parameter value. With `##`, `get` and `funName` are separate tokens, which means the precompiler can replace `funName` and then concatenate the results.